# failed to load sql modules into the database cluster

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, postgresql-14

I tried to install postgreSQL v14.1.1 x64 in my windows 10 but on completion I got an error

> "failed to load sql modules into the database cluster".

But the app still runs, so opened "pgadmin4", entered the postgres user password while connecting to server and got the following error

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

P.S. I didn't make any changes to port while installing it is 5432 and while setting the password its a plain text, no special characters included.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. SQL Server and PostgreSQL are two completely different products

Comment: sorry, might have mistakenly selected that tag. And it would be really helpful if you could help me with the issue above.

Comment: Is the service running? The error says pgAdmin couldn't even connect to the database. This isn't a password issue. In almost all such cases either the service wasn't running or a firewall (in this case Windows Firewall) was blocking the port. `Connection Refused` means the OS itself refused to establish a connection to that port, either because it's blocked or because no service or appp is listening on it.

Comment: how to fix it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did the following things and it solved for me :

1. Winkey + R > %temp%  "Deleted all files/Cleared Cached files.
2. Winkey + R > services.msc > scroll down to "postgresql" > right click to "Properties" > switch to "Log On" section > select "This Account" > click "Browse" and search for system administator name and write valid password > click "Apply" + "Ok"
3. Now run server, the issue is fixed.
4. Make sure to check "Automatic" option is enabled in services.msc>postgresql